# Unable to stream a video from a remote server in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, video-streaming

I am trying to play a video based on a remote server but it will not load. However, if the video is on the local filesytem it does work. Here is the code:

```
@GetMapping("/media")
    public ResponseEntity<ResourceRegion> getMedia(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        Resource media = null;
        try {
            media = new UrlResource("http://remoteserver.com:80/movie/377f87f5f5/234180c7a2/156022.mp4");
            // media = new FileUrlResource(VideoUploadingDir + "/video.mp4");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        log.info("mediaType  is {}",MediaTypeFactory.getMediaType(media));
        
        ResourceRegion region = null;
        region = resourceRegion(media, headers);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .contentType(MediaTypeFactory.getMediaType(media)
                        .orElse(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM))
                .body(region);
    }

    private ResourceRegion resourceRegion(Resource media, HttpHeaders headers) {
        long contentLength = 0;
        contentLength = getContentSizeFromUrl(media);
        log.info("contentLength is {}", contentLength);
        
        List<HttpRange> rangeList = new ArrayList<HttpRange>();
                
        rangeList.add(HttpRange.createByteRange(0, contentLength));
        
        
        headers.setRange(rangeList);
        List<HttpRange> range = headers.getRange();
        log.info("range is {}", headers.getRange().toString());
        
        if (!range.isEmpty()) {
            String[] ranges = range.get(0).toString().split("-");
            long start = Long.parseLong(ranges[0]);
            log.info("start is {}", start);
            
            long end = ranges.length > 1 ? Long.parseLong(ranges[1]) : contentLength - 1;
            log.info("end is {}", end);
            
            long rangeLength = Math.min(end - start + 1, contentLength);
            log.info("rangeLength is {}", rangeLength);
            
            return new ResourceRegion(media, start, rangeLength);
        } else {
            long rangeLength = Math.min(1024 * 1024, contentLength);
            log.info("rangeLength is {}", rangeLength);
            
            return new ResourceRegion(media, 0, rangeLength);
        }
```

This is some output from logging:

```
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.035[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m mediaType  is Optional[video/mp4]
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.312[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m contentLength is 1878020797
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.313[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m range is [0-1878020797]
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.313[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m start is 0
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.313[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m end is 1878020797
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.313[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-9][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m rangeLength is 1878020797
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.617[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m mediaType  is Optional[video/mp4]
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.873[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m contentLength is 1878020797
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.873[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m range is [0-1878020797]
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.873[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m start is 0
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.873[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m end is 1878020797
[2m2023-08-27 21:04:03.873[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m171969[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8081-exec-10][0;39m [36mc.s.controller.VideoStreamController    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m rangeLength is 1878020797
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I would expect the video to play irrespective of where it is located. The same URL plays fine if I just paste the URL into a browser.